# use php variable in wordpress page

Tags: php

I am using Wordpress for my clients to log into the site, put data in a customized table and save it in a database table.
Through the code “example” that I put in funtions.php theme I can return my email at the top of the screen. Code below.

```
$ current_user = wp_get_current_user ();
$ logado1 = $ current_user-> user_email;  
echo $ logged1;
```

however through a new blank page I can put the HTML to make it work correctly, including with the css via plugin.
But I can't include the php on the page is to retrieve the data from the $ logado1 variable contained in theme / funtions.php.
Well, I need to retrieve the data from “$ logado1 email”, and forward it to a next php referenced in.

```
<form action=" http://localhost/newphp.php" method="post">.
```

do the treatment and save it in a new table in the “registration” database.

```
<div class = "divsearch">
<form action=" http://localhost/newphp.php" method="post">
<label class = "textout"> <b> Port 1 </b> </label>
<input type = "text" class = "box1">
<label class = "textout"> <b> Port 2 </b> </label>
<input type = "text" class = "box1">
</form>
<button type = "submit" class = "buttonacept1"> Save </button>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any solution for this problem ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by sabbir you have to create a custom template to use php code, other way is to register a shortcode and the use that shortcode on new page. creating shortcode is much easier, you can paste the code below in functions.php and then use [new_form] shortcode on your page. You can modify the code as per your needs...

```
function form_shortcode() 
    {   
        if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user ();
            $logado1 = $current_user->user_email;  
            ob_start();         
        ?>
            <div class = "divsearch">
                <form action=" http://localhost/newphp.php" method="post">
                    <label class = "textout"> <b> Port 1 </b> </label>
                    <input type = "text" class = "box1">
                    <label class = "textout"> <b> Port 2 </b> </label>
                    <input type = "text" class = "box1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="user-email" id="user-email" value="<?php echo $logged1 ?>">;
                </form>
                <button type = "submit" class = "buttonacept1"> Save </button>
            </div>
        <?php                               
        }
        $content=ob_get_clean();
        return $content;
    }
    add_shortcode('new_form', 'form_shortcode');
```

Comment: thank you very much, it solved my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add php within visual editor or text editor by default. WordPress doesn't allow that. If you need a custom html page as a page you can always use a page template. Read more about page template [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/).

For minor cases you can use a plugin to add php as shortcode. **Insert Php Snippet** is a good one. You can read how to use the plugin [here](https://www.greengeeks.com/tutorials/article/insert-php-code-wordpress-posts-pages/).

Comment: thank you very much for the suggestion, or our friend's code below solved perfectly.
because with snippet pluggin it caused many errors